# Prove $10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2$ is divisible by $45$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Basically, I have to use Euler theorem to prove that 
$10n^8 -9n^6 -n^2$ is divisible by $45$

So my approach so far is to say

$10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2 = 0 \bmod 45$

Now $45$ can be factored into $5$ and $9$

So I figure I need to do something like

$10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2 \bmod 5$

$10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2 \bmod 9$

But I am not sure how to exactly prove it.

I know how to prove something like $n^{13} - n$ is a multiple of $2730$ using Fermat's theorem, but the proof works nicely because the exponent is a prime. My approach to $n^{13} - n$ would consist of proving that $n^{13} - n$ is divisible by $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13\}$.

What is throwing me off is the coefficients in $10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2$ and the fact that the exponents are not primes.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not considering induction to prove it?

Comment: I am asked specifically to use Euler's Theorem. Basically my professor quickly went over this and Didnt use induction to solve it. I am just trying to get a better understanding by myself.

Comment: What throws me off is why can you ask those specific questions? Where do you get n^2 = n^6 mod 5, n^4 = n mod 3.

Comment: We will try to group terms which don't automatically zero out together somehow.  E.g. if $n^2\equiv n^6\mod 5$ then $-9n^6 - n^2 \equiv -9n^2 - n^2 \equiv -10n^2 \equiv \dots $.  For the record, it wasn't true that $n^4\equiv n\mod 3$ (take $n=-1$ for counterexample), but it does turn out to be true that $n^8\equiv n^2\mod 9$, which takes just a bit more effort.

Comment: I feel silly now. I was understanding why 10n^8 disappeared, but I couldnt wrap my head around the -9n^6. I just now realized that 9 is congruent to -1 mod 5. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2\equiv0\mod5$, it is enough to show $n^6-n^2\equiv0\mod5$. This follows from $n^5\equiv n\mod5$.

To prove $10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2\equiv0\mod9$, it is enough to show $n^8-n^2\equiv0\mod9$. This follows from $n^7\equiv n\mod9$, since $\phi(9)=6$.

Comment: I have one last question which i really should have specified in my original post. Does this work for any integer n? The question that was given emphasized that it must work for any integer n.

Comment: What do you mean by "work for any integer $n$"? I didn't use any property other than $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$10n^8 - 9n^6 - n^2\equiv  0n^8-(-1)n^6 - n^2 \equiv n^6 - n^2 \pmod 5$$

By little fermat we have $n^5\equiv n \pmod 5$, therefore
$$n^6-n^2\equiv n\cdot n^5-n^2\equiv n\cdot n-n^2\equiv n^2-n^2\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

See if you can work the other mod similarly